# EclipseLink-3002 (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, javafx, eclipselink

Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [¬íhoraInicioq
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:75)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper.buildBytesFromHexString(Helper.java:266)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToByteArray(ConversionManager.java:321)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:136)

I get this error in this class:
@Entity
public class DiaDoEvento implements Serializable {

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dia;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horaInicio;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horaFim;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Comment: What's the fully qualified type name of the Date type you're using, what type and format is it in the underlying storage, and why are you using a 7 year old build of EclipseLink?

Comment: There is no byteArray or anything in there that relates to a byteArray conversion, so the error doesn't mean or isn't coming from what you are stating it is, unless your Time/Date types in the database aren't date/time types. Something is giving EclipseLink a string and requiring it to map to a byte Array when it isn't possible - the string is '[¬íhoraInicioq'